# How run test suite JUnit5-based?

Tags: junit, junit4, junit5, runner

I want to create runner for my test classes that based on JUnit-5.

In the first I tried to use with this construction.

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SelectClasses(UserAPITest.class)
public class UserAPITestRunner {
}
```

But in doesn't work. If I understand correctly, then with the help of such a runner I can run JUnit4 based.

How we can run suite JUnit5 tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Techically, if you are using `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` that is a suite in JUnit 5. It just uses JUnit 4 to launch the JUnit 5 Platform.

From [the documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-junit-platform-runner-test-suite):

> Test classes and suites annotated with @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class) cannot be executed directly on the JUnit Platform (or as a "JUnit 5" test as documented in some IDEs). Such classes and suites can only be executed using JUnit 4 infrastructure.